# Apache redirect to external site with directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirection

I have some requests like

```
blogs.bobvilapaint.com/11/11/2011/title
```

which I would like to redirect to

```
staging.bobvila.com/blogs/title
```

I've written

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9/]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)$ http://staging.bobvila.com/blogs/$1 [R,L]
```

But instead of being redirected to

```
staging.bobvila.com/blogs/title
```

Its being redirected to

```
staging.bobvila.com/title
```

So I don't understand why the redirect rule its eating the "blogs" directory on the redirection to the new server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression may not be correct,

Try with this :

RewriteRule ^[0-9/]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*) http://staging.bobvila.com/blogs/$1 [L]

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried with that rule, and then I go to http://blogs.bobvilapaint.com/07/11/2011/how-to-install-door-hardware but the rule is still eating the "blogs" word :(

Comment: can you paste here the address you are typing on browser, and the address that it should be redirected to ?

Comment: Please, also ensure that you do not have another .htaccess that could be overriding the current configuration. Maybe you are redirectioning something on the blogs folder, and thats why it gets deleted.

Comment: I'm typing http://blogs.bobvilapaint.com/07/11/2011/how-to-install-door-hardware and I should be redirected to http://staging.bobvila.com/blogs/how-to-install-door-hardware

Comment: You are totally right, the problem was with another redirection rules on the .htaccess
Thank you a lot, I spent hours trying to figure out what the problem was :)

Comment: I just did :) It took a bit, but the vote is there